# Formatting dynamic regex expression

Tags: javascript, regex

Just curious. what are the differences between?

```
var a=text.replace(/(Nullam|ligula|in)/ig,'`<b>$1</b>`');
```

with

```
var string = "Nullam|lingula|in";  
var pattern = new RegExp (string, "ig");    
var a=text.replace(pattern ,'`<b>$1</b>`');
```

This should gives out the same result, but it doesn't. Any thoughts?

Thank you

Comment: If you wrote `$0` instead of `$1` in your second example, then you'd get the same result in both. Actually, you'd also get that if you used `$0` in the first example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing parens in your later statement, so there are no captures. And the flag is `gi`, not `ig` (although I'm not sure if this makes any difference)

```
var reString = "(Nullam|lingula|in)"; var pattern = new RegExp (reString, "gi");
```

Comment: For example, when the first technique found one of words, it will make it bold, and wont' replace the word. Meanwhile, when the second one found one of words, it will make it bold and literally it will replace the word to "$1". That is what comes out from my experiment. What I am trying to achieve is to just make the word bold without literally replace the word. Is this possible? (with dynamic keywords)

Comment: Yes, and that's because you're missing the parens which creates a capture group.

Comment: Following your suggestion. I tried and cannot get it to work. Here are my experiments: 

First technique http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/q8S7E/
 AND 
Second technique: http://jsfiddle.net/UyWTf/1/

Comment: You're not loading jQuery in the fiddle. This works in chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/UyWTf/2/

Comment: Interesting. It works in Chrome. Somehow after clearing all the caches and etc, it works now in Firefox. Anyway, I am still learning about RegExp. Thank you very much for your help. I really appreciate it.